# Get ID from MIDI devices in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, midi

I'm a musician and a programmer and would like to create my own program to make music.
I'll start with a console application in C++ before I make a GUI.

I'm quiet new to C/C++ and know how to make a basic console application and have read about the Win32 API.

I was looking into MSDN for multimedia in Win32 applications and I found a lot of functions for MIDI: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd798495(VS.85).aspx

I can receive how many MIDI devices are plugged in this way:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << midiInGetNumDevs();
    cout << " MIDI devices connected" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But now i want to find out how these devices are called, with the `midiInGetID` function I think and a `while` loop. Can somebody help me with this? The function requires a `HMIDIIN` parameter and I don't know how I can get one since almost all the MIDI functions use this parameter.

I know this is not the most obvious topic but it would be great if someone could help me.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get information, you loop calling [midiInGetDevCaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd798453(VS.85).aspx), with a first parameter varying from 0 included to the result of `midiInGetNumDevs` excluded.  Each call fills a [MIDIINCAPS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd798451(VS.85).aspx) struct (you pass a pointer to the struct when you call the function) with information about the Nth device.  To **open** a device, and fill the HMIDIIN needed for other calls, you call [midiInOpen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd798458(VS.85).aspx) with the device number (again, 0 to N-1 included) as the second parameter.

The same concept applies to output devices, except that the names have `Out` instead of `In` (and for the structures `OUT` instead of `IN`).

Comment: I replied to you in a new answer, because I can't markup my code here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. I didn't know `midiInGetDevCaps` requires a call to the specific properties of it to return the device name.

Here is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    unsigned int devCount = midiInGetNumDevs();
    cout << devCount << " MIDI devices connected:" << endl;
    MIDIINCAPS inputCapabilities;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < devCount; i++) {
        midiInGetDevCaps(i, &inputCapabilities, sizeof(inputCapabilities));
        cout << "[" << i << "] " << inputCapabilities.szPname << endl;
    }
}
```

And thanks for your help!