# Is it possible to find bcd device or device class using win API midi function?

Tags: c++, winapi

Can anyone please let me know if there is a way to find the bcd device or device class using win API midi function.

for example:

```
DWORD out_string;

midiInMessage( (HMIDIIN) device_id , DRV_QUERYDEVICEINTERFACE, out_string, <DRV_QUERYDEVICEINTERFACESIZE> );
```

From out_string we get a string something like

```
"\\?\usb#vid_2ae2&pid_1388#abcdef0123456789#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}"
```

using this we can get the vendor id and product id but is there anyway to get the bcd device or device?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1962281/62576

Comment: Thank you, but it does not MIDIINCAPS structure used in midiInGetDevCaps does not returns bcd device always. some times it returns 0, while you can see the bcd device in usb view tree when a midi device is connected